# How to autofill an field value for other model in Odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

This is a re-work on MRO module that is available from this link - https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/mro/

Following is the sequence of workflow

1) Maintenance Request will be created and and then after confirming it is proceeded to Maintenance Order

2) When Maintenance Order is processed and finally reaches the state 'done', maintenance request document which was origin of the order will also reach the state 'done'.

There are two classes

mro.request

```
class mro_request(osv.osv):
    """
    Maintenance Requests
    """
    _name = 'mro.request'
    _description = 'Maintenance Request'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

    STATE_SELECTION = [
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('claim', 'Claim'),
        ('run', 'Execution'),
        ('done', 'Done'),
        ('reject', 'Rejected'),
        ('cancel', 'Canceled')
    ]

    _track = {
        'state': {
            'mro.mt_request_sent': lambda self, cr, uid, obj, ctx=None: obj['state'] == 'claim',
            'mro.mt_request_confirmed': lambda self, cr, uid, obj, ctx=None: obj['state'] == 'run',
            'mro.mt_request_rejected': lambda self, cr, uid, obj, ctx=None: obj['state'] == 'reject',
        },
    }

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Reference', size=64),
        'state': fields.selection(STATE_SELECTION, 'Status', readonly=True,
            help="When the maintenance request is created the status is set to 'Draft'.\n\
            If the request is sent the status is set to 'Claim'.\n\
            If the request is confirmed the status is set to 'Execution'.\n\
            If the request is rejected the status is set to 'Rejected'.\n\
            When the maintenance is over, the status is set to 'Done'."),
        'asset_id': fields.many2one('asset.asset', 'Asset', required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
        'cause': fields.char('Cause', size=64, translate=True, required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
        'description': fields.text('Description', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
        'reject_reason': fields.text('Reject Reason', readonly=True),
        'requested_date': fields.datetime('Requested Date', required=True, select=1, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, help="Date requested by the customer for maintenance."),
        'execution_date': fields.datetime('Execution Date', required=True, select=1, readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)],'claim':[('readonly',False)]}),
        'breakdown': fields.boolean('Breakdown', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
        'create_uid': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Responsible'),
    }

    _defaults = {
        'state': 'draft',
        'requested_date': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        'execution_date': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        'breakdown': False,
    }
```

and then there is mro.order class

```
class mro_order(osv.osv):
    """
    Maintenance Orders
    """
    _name = 'mro.order'
    _description = 'Maintenance Order'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

    STATE_SELECTION = [
        ('draft', 'DRAFT'),
        ('released', 'WAITING PARTS'),
        ('ready', 'READY TO MAINTENANCE'),
        ('done', 'DONE'),
        ('cancel', 'CANCELED')
    ]

    MAINTENANCE_TYPE_SELECTION = [
        ('bm', 'Breakdown'),
        ('cm', 'Corrective')
    ]

    _track = {
        'state': {
            'mro.mt_order_confirmed': lambda self, cr, uid, obj, ctx=None: obj['state'] == 'ready',
        },
    }

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Reference', size=64),
        'origin': fields.char('Source Document', size=64, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]},
            help="Reference of the document that generated this maintenance order."),
        'state': fields.selection(STATE_SELECTION, 'Status', readonly=True,
            help="When the maintenance order is created the status is set to 'Draft'.\n\
            If the order is confirmed the status is set to 'Waiting Parts'.\n\
            If the stock is available then the status is set to 'Ready to Maintenance'.\n\
            When the maintenance is over, the status is set to 'Done'."),
        'maintenance_type': fields.selection(MAINTENANCE_TYPE_SELECTION, 'Maintenance Type', required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
        'task_id': fields.many2one('mro.task', 'Task', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
        'description': fields.char('Description', size=64, translate=True, required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
        'asset_id': fields.many2one('asset.asset', 'Asset', required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
        'date_planned': fields.datetime('Planned Date', required=True, select=1, readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)]}),
        'date_scheduled': fields.datetime('Scheduled Date', required=True, select=1, readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)],'released':[('readonly',False)],'ready':[('readonly',False)]}),
        'date_execution': fields.datetime('Execution Date', required=True, select=1, readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)],'released':[('readonly',False)],'ready':[('readonly',False)]}),
        'parts_lines': fields.one2many('mro.order.parts.line', 'maintenance_id', 'Planned parts',
            readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)]}),
        'parts_ready_lines': fields.function(_get_available_parts, relation="stock.move", method=True, type="one2many", multi='parts'),
        'parts_move_lines': fields.function(_get_available_parts, relation="stock.move", method=True, type="one2many", multi='parts'),
        'parts_moved_lines': fields.function(_get_available_parts, relation="stock.move", method=True, type="one2many", multi='parts'),
        'tools_description': fields.text('Tools Description',translate=True),
        'labor_description': fields.text('Labor Description',translate=True),
        'operations_description': fields.text('Operations Description',translate=True),
        'documentation_description': fields.text('Documentation Description',translate=True),
        'problem_description': fields.text('Problem Description'),
        'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company','Company',required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)]}),
        'procurement_group_id': fields.many2one('procurement.group', 'Procurement group', copy=False),
    }

    _defaults = {
        'state': lambda *a: 'draft',
        'maintenance_type': lambda *a: 'bm',
        'date_planned': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        'date_scheduled': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        'date_execution': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        'company_id': lambda self, cr, uid, c: self.pool.get('res.company')._company_default_get(cr, uid, 'mro.order', context=c),
    }
```

And then there is a button which is "Done" which will complete the flow of the Maintenance Order

```
def action_done(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            self.pool.get('stock.move').action_done(cr, uid, [x.id for x in order.parts_move_lines])
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'done', 'date_execution': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')})
        return True
```

I wanted such that when "DONE" button is clicked, the value of "date_execution" field value of MRO.ORDER to be updated to "Execution Date" field of MRO.REQUEST

For this scenario, i was trying with following code:

```
def action_done(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        sobj = self.pool.get('mro.request')
        sobj1 = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
        for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            ref_date = sobj1.date_execution
            self.pool.get('stock.move').action_done(cr, uid, [x.id for x in order.parts_move_lines])
            sobj2 = sobj.browse(cr, uid, ids, [('name','=','sobj1.origin')])
            sobj2.write(cr, uid, ids, {'execution_date':'ref_date'})
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'done', 'date_execution': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')})
        return True
```

Well, till now I am not able to succeed. Anyone with suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks !!!

Comment: what is the result instead? any error?

Comment: No error, nothing, at the same time it does not reflect the result what I expected. I think I am missing something ..

Comment: What is the relation between mro.order and mro.request? (If you have an mro.order, how can you tell which mro.request it was created from?)

Comment: Right now, it does not have an relation, I had thought of adding an many2one between mro.order and mro.request, but could not conclude it.